# DAX: How to filter table

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax

How to filter Table in DAX:

**Example** ([.pbix](https://github.com/DenisSipchenko/Power-BI/blob/9df7fe8d233141b77b04c94bcba7d11000dad64d/Questions/DAX%20HowToFilterTable.pbix)):
How to return only "highlighted yellow" rows (rows with **max `dy_UpCst`** per **`ki_File`**)?

[image]

P.S. I know how to do it with **SQL** or **PowerQuery**. In two steps: 1) get table with `ki_File` and max `dy_UpCst`, 2) join all necessary values from source table

But I don't know how to do it with DAX.

And, as far as I know, DAX could contain very elegant solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula to generate a ranking column, assuming that in your case ID column is ki_File and DATE column is dy_UpCst. In this way if you filter by the ranking column, selecting value=1 you will highlight the rows you desire.

```
Rank = 
VAR x = 'Table'[ki_File]
VAR y = 'Table'[dy_UpCst]
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        RANK.EQ ( y, 'Table'[dy_UpCst], DESC ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), 'Table'[ki_File] = x )
    )
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: don't work. returns errors for 2nd and 3rd row `var x='Table'[ID]
var y='Table'[DATE]`. P.S. *.pbix is available for download

Comment: Ok, now clear. It should be new column (not measure or table)